# Pivottable selection using slicer, is there any way to get source data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am using a Slicer to filter data in a Pivot table.
If I double click in the Pivot table I get the source data for that row.

But I would like to get the source data for the entire Pivot table, 
after it is filtered with slicer, how can I do this?

Comment: No, my pivot table didn't ahve any sums. But putting sums there and double clicking solved the problem. Thanks @pnuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pivot table didn't have any sums. But putting sums there and double clicking solved the problem.